# Why is there no byte data type in WebAssembly?

Tags: webassembly

Given how useful byte data types are for stings and binary data why does WebAssembly not have them? Since it would require bit operations to access individual bytes, is there an overhead to using byte data over storing each byte in its own 32 bit int?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebAssembly locals & globals are strongly mapped to today’s hardware registers. That’s why they aren’t byte-sized.

You can still work with bytes using `i32.load8_u`, `v128.load8x8_u` and so on. These instructions more closely match what a real CPU does. Introducing a "byte type" would add syntactic sugar & complexity for no real benefit, because CPUs always use 32/64 bit registers in the end.

In addition, byte-sized locals would completely muck up the alignment of the stack after a push.

To the second question: there is no difference. `i32.load` is the same speed as `i32.load8_u` on modern CPUs. There aren't any explicit “bit operations" going on, it's a single instruction (e.g. `mov al, [mem]`). The byte is moved into the lower 8 bits of the register, that’s all.

In fact, it's possible that an `i32.load` can be *slower* than an `i32.load8_u` if its address isn't aligned properly. (Bytes are *always* aligned because they're not big enough to cross an alignment boundary).

Answer (score 0):

WebAssembly intentionally avoids certain high-level features and data types that are available in languages like JavaScript.

It increases the **simplicity** of it by not including datatypes like byte which could add complexity to it, also it keeps the datatypes to minimal to increase **portability**.

Webassembly also uses a linear memory model that allows programs to read and write bytes of memory directly. There isn't a specific "byte" type, WebAssembly provides facilities for working with bytes, including loading and storing bytes
Its to create a **Predictable Memory Layout**.